# Keras: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible layer issues

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am using Keras with Tensorflow as backends and get incompatible errors:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_dim = 1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(16))
```

The following error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_lstm_model.py", line 36, in <module>
    model.add(LSTM(16))
  File "/home/***/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 332, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/***/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 529, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(x)
  File "/home/***/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 469, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

How can I fix this problem?

Keras version: 1.2.2
Tensorflow version: 0.12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `LSTM` layer is accepting input in shape of `(len_of_sequences, nb_of_features)`. The input shape you provided is only `1-dim` so this where error comes from. The exact form of error message comes from the fact that the actual shape of data includes the `batch_size`. So the actual shape of data fed to the layer is `(batch_size, len_of_sequences, nb_of_features)`. Your shape is `(batch_size, 1)` and this is the reason behind `3d` vs `2d` inputs.

Moreover - you might have a similiar problem with a second layer. In order to make your `LSTM` layer to return a sequences you should change its definition to:

```
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape = (len_of_seq, nb_of_features), return_sequences=True)
```

or:

```
model.add(LSTM(64, input_dim = nb_of_features, input_len = len_of_sequence, return_sequences=True)
```

Comment: I have verified that it works by only setting the `input_dim` alone, conditioning that setting the `return_sequences` to True. Could you tell me why I have to set the `return_sequences`?

Comment: You should set the return_srquences to True every time your output is fed to a recurrent network. It makes your layer to output the whole sequence of computations. If it's set to false a one dimensional vector is returned (by default it's set to the last output of a sequence).

Comment: Is my answer correct or wrong?